# Is it possible to restore table without backup in postgres

Tags: backup, sql, postgresql

I have made some unfortunate UPDATE on a Postgresql table. Is it possible to reverse that change without any backup / rollback save etc?

Comment: yea start typing.

Comment: Y U NO BACKUP??

Answer (score 2):

NO. You've just moved to admin category which makes backups.

Comment: funny but not funny....

Comment: +1 for learning the hard way

Comment: Im not an admin of that server :D If i were i would have a backup ;;

Answer (score -2):

You could restore it by dropping the table (make sure link from other tables aren't connected to it) and applying the SQL script that was created before you made the update. In other words, use the previous script and apply it. If you don't have a previous script, start writing it out so it is exactly the way the table was before you applied this 'unfortunate' update. Good luck!

Comment: Uhm.. A script usually creates the table scheme, not the data in the table..

Comment: Why would you drop the *whole* table?